# Unit testing on JavaScript : dependencies for testing on Karma, jasmine and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jasmine, karma-runner

I've developed an application with AngularJS and some extra tools based on bootstrap.
now I want to test everything.
but I have a problem with Karma and jasmine.
the problem is that karma create an exception when i launch the tests...

the exception is a TypError, the object is not a method (sorry, it's in french on my console)

here is my karma.conf.js :

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

basePath: '',

frameworks: ['jasmine'],

files: [
  'src/test/lib/angular/angular.js',
  'src/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
  'src/test/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js',
  'src/test/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js', 
  'src/main/webapp/resources/js/pages/*.js',
  'src/main/webapp/resources/js/pages/survey/*.js',
  'src/main/webapp/resources/js/pages/billing/*.js',
  'src/test/*Spec.js',
  'src/test/survey/*Spec.js',
  'src/test/billing/*Spec.js',
],
exclude: [
],

preprocessors: {
},

reporters: ['progress'],

port: 9876,

colors: true,

logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

autoWatch: true,

browsers: ['IE', 'Firefox'],

junitReporter: {
        outputFile: 'unit.xml',
        suite: 'unit'
}
});
};
```

in my JSP and JS, I use a bootstrap-select library by silvio moreto : http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

and this is the code that create the exception :

```
angular.module("searchSurveyApp", [])
 .controller("searchSurveyController" , function($scope, $http,$window) {


    ...

    $("#selectpicker").selectpicker(); // <= launches exception in karma
```

and, finally, this is the js test :

```
describe('Unit: searchSurveyController', function() {
  // Load the module with MainController
  beforeEach(module('searchSurveyApp'));

  var ctrl, scope, http;
  // inject the $controller and $rootScope services
  // in the beforeEach block
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $http) {
    // Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    http = $http;
    // Create the controller
    ctrl = $controller('searchSurveyController', {
      $scope: scope,
      $http: http
    });
  }));


  it('should write hello', 
    function() {
      console.log("hello");
  });

});
```

if I remove this : $("#selectpicker").selectpicker();
the test is OK.
so, I ask you, how can i test this kind of code ?

thanks for by advance, because i really stuck on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not just use DOM in your unit tests, because that is UNIT test, not end-2-end. There is no real DOM available in jasmine environment. Stuff like "$("#selectpicker").selectpicker();" should be incapsulated inside directives, and you can test directives separately using other methods with virtual DOM ( https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-unit-testing-a-directive )

In your services or factories you want to test any DOM operations are untestable, so refactor your service in proper way to extract any DOM work to directives

Comment: you were right ! i transform all my select picker into a cool directive, and now, it works, thanks a lot !